# Print export popup box displaces text on the page

Tags: html, css, html-table, styling

In the application, the user can view charts such as the one below. It contains detailed information about what the lines represent:

[image: Here is my chart before I initiate print]

Here is the code for the legend (text):

```
<table class="P1Table" style="height:auto !important; margin-top:5px; border:none; width:95%; overflow:hidden; margin-left:10px;">
   <tr>
      <td style="width:6%;"></td>
      <td style="width:47%; text-align:center;max-height:12px;">LTD</td>
      <td style="width:47%; text-align:center;max-height:12px;">YTD</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:white;">
      <td style="width:6% !important; max-height:12px; background-color:#008EE4 !important; border:1px solid white"></td>
      <td id="MatterLTDValueID">
         "data"
      </td>
      <td style="width:47%; text-align:center;" id="MatterAdHocValueID">
         "data"
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:6% !important;max-height:12px; background-color:#f68415 !important; border:1px solid white;"></td>
      <td id="BenchmarkLTDValueID">
         "data"
      </td>
      <td id="BenchmarkAdHocValueID">
         "data"
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The issue is that whenever I use the print function, the print export popup box for some reason distorts the text in the chart. The popup is just the generic one that appears when you try to print anything on a page.

[image: Here is what the text on the chart looks like afterwards.]

Does anyone know what could possibly be causing this to happen? When the print popup appears as a separate window altogether, so I do not believe that it should be affecting anything on the page.

Answer (score 0):

While I did not figure out exactly the cause beyond it, I fixed the issue by doing this:

```
td { padding:0px; }
```